# Does Google Actually Deindex 410 pages faster than 404?

Tags: search-engine-indexing, google-index, thin-content

Most of the pages in blog need to delete, because those are thin content. Though it's already ranked in first page and enough visitor. but i really do not want to have those pages on my site (due to not exact audience focused according to site niche).

So now what will be best to delete those pages and to deindex from google as well. 404 or 410? which will work faster to perform the task perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 410 pages do deindex a bit faster than 404 pages, once Google sees them.

[According to Mueller from Google](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-404-status/254429/):

> The subtle difference here is that a 410 will sometimes fall out a little bit faster than a 404. But usually, we’re talking on the order of a couple days or so.

That being said, Google needs to crawl them before they will be able to find the 404/410. If Google isn't crawling as fast as you'd like, submit your URLs to the [Search Console Removal Tool](https://search.google.com/search-console/removals).